# Библиотеки для поиска и анализа кривых на изображении

Tags: c++, c, opencv

Приветствую.
Допустим, имеется изображение:
[image: Три кривых на светлом фоне]
На данном изображении три кривых (графика),
части которых могут быть разной толщины или пунктирные/штриховые.
Линии всегда темные на светлом фоне, может присутствовать сглаживание.
Помимо этих линий также присутствует текст и сетка (но это легкая побочка, не суть).
Необходимо на изображении найти эти кривые, их количество, определить их толщину (примерно) в указанной точке кривой, определить к какой кривой относится указанная точка, разбить кривую на отрезки, чтобы можно было впоследствии приблизительно восстановить кривую по координатам.

Справится ли с таким OpenCV? Может быть имеются готовые библиотеки для анализа графиков? В общем, пните в верном направлении.

Comment: Для начала почитайте про контуры и морфологические операции

Comment: Может быть вот это: http://robocraft.ru/blog/computervision/640.html Вас заинтересует ?

Comment: Есть ещё такая книжка:
https://www.books.ru/books/raspoznavanie-prostykh-linii-na-izobrazhenii-4657857/